# In R, why are the results of summary(lm(y~-1))$sigma^2 and mean(y^2) same?

Tags: r, regression, self-study, variance, mean

Consider the following data and the model:

```
y <- c(9,3,-2,7,6,12)
lm(y~-1)

summary(lm(y~-1))$sigma^2
[1] 53.83333
```

I expected `var(y)` will give the same result of `summary(lm(y~-1))$sigma^2`. But, it did not give, rather `mean(y^2)` gave same result? Isn't formula of `mean(y^2)` is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2}{n}$? Why are the results of `summary(lm(y~-1))$sigma^2` and `mean(y^2)` same?

```
var(y)
[1] 23.76667

mean(y^2)
[1] 53.83333
```

Answer (score 7):

If you define the model as `lm(y~1)`, you will get a value of 23.76667 for `sigma^2`.

Your model does not have an intercept (that's the `-1` in the formula), which is equivalent to stating that the `y` values come from a population with mean zero. Your estimate of the population variance is, thus, $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2}{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

`summary(lm(y~-1))$sigma^2` gives the variance of the residuals from your model, but your model is one that doesn't fit any parameters and just predicts $0$ every time: $\hat y_i = 0\space\space\forall\space\space i$. There are no parameters estimated from the data. Therefore, the residuals are the $y$-values themselves, and their variance is calculated assuming a degrees of freedom equal to the sample size itself (you don't lose a degree of freedom estimating the mean).

$$
\text{var}\left(\hat\varepsilon\right) = \dfrac{\sum_i y_i}{N}
$$

This is exactly the identity you observe.